# DB reset after pushing to openshift

Tags: sinatra, openshift, ruby-datamapper

I have a Sinatra project that I'm publishing through Openshift.

Every time I'm pushing the changes to the openshift remote, the datebasse is reset.

I'm using sqlite3 with DataMapper

From DataMapper init file

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/main.db")

<my object here>

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

/config.ru

```
require './App'
require 'rubygems'

run Sinatra::Application
```

What could be the reason? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance data is dropped during OpenShift deploys. Persistent data should be stored in the location specified by the environment variable `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`. Move your database file there.